# Multiple uses of one tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The other day I noticed there was no info for the [reactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactive) tag and figured I could quickly edit the info, so I went ahead and did so. I ignorantly assumed that the tag was only used for the R programming language in reference to shiny. While ~60-70% of the use regarding this tag is for the purpose mentioned above, it also is used for other purposes (e.g. Java). I am sure this problem must have arisen at some other point so would someone please point me in the correct direction? I am not sure whether to put in a request to delete the edit, or change the tag to be more general? If there are any examples of tags that serve multiple definitions I would appreciate you linking them in order to see how one goes about this.

The [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reactive/info) in question.

Comment: It is a programming concept, most users use the tag that matches the library name.  Like [shiny] in the case of [r].  Sure, [java] doesn't seem blessed with a popular library name.  The primary tag disambiguates it.  You could propose it as a synonym for [reactive-programming].